# a combobox creates and opens a Datepicker element and the selected date is automatically entered into the textbox value in front

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

This design is inside the transaction page! if the user wants to search a transaction by its date, clicks the 'by date' Combobox, then appears a datepicker element, the user chooses/picks a date from the datepicker then the chosen date appears as string into the textbox.

I've a combobox with following elements into it.

```
<ComboBox Width="105" 
          SelectedIndex="0">
     <ComboBoxItem Name="TrSearchByName"
                   Content="by First Name"/>
     <ComboBoxItem Name="TrSearchByLastName"
                   Content="by Last Name"/>
     <ComboBoxItem Name="TrSearchByAmount"
                   Content="by Amount"/>
     <ComboBoxItem Name="TrSearchByDate"
                   Content="by Date"
                   Selected="PickDateUp"/>
</ComboBox>
```

and one Textbox element (ByDate) in front of it. If the Combobox (By Date) is selected, a datepicker elements appears and the user picks a date up, then the selected date is the value of the Textbox element (ByDate) automatically. The event handler C# code is:

```
private void PickDateUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       DatePicker choose = new DatePicker();
      //here wanna work further!
   }
```

please help!

Comment: Hi, Your design is very complicated. Maybe you can describe the whole problem, I would tell you how to make it easier, if it does not work then I will try to write you a solution.

Comment: If I understand your goal correctly, the solution will need to involve DataBindings, ViewModels (INotifypropertyChanged) and maybe Datatemplating. These topics are pretty extensive to handle them this way. You may first want to get familiar with these concepts.

Comment: @Maksym I have updated the question. Hopefully it is clearer now. thanks for your all replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it can help.
MainWindow.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public string SearchValue { get; set; }
        public SearchParameter SelectedParameter { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        private void DoSearch(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchValue) ||
                TrSearchBy.SelectedIndex < 0 ||
                TrSearchBy.SelectedIndex > TrSearchBy.Items.Count -1)
                return;

            if (SelectedParameter.Value == "Date")
            {
                //Search by date
                DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(SearchValue);
            }
            else
            {
                //Search by others
            }
        }
    }

    public class SearchParameter
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public Control Content { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test" 
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="186" Width="345">
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <TextBox x:Key="TextBoxValue" Text="{Binding SearchValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
        <DatePicker x:Key="DatePickerValue" Text="{Binding SearchValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ValuePresenter">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <x:Array x:Key="SearchParameters" Type="{x:Type local:SearchParameter}">
            <local:SearchParameter Value="First name" Content="{StaticResource TextBoxValue}"/>
            <local:SearchParameter Value="Last name" Content="{StaticResource TextBoxValue}"/>
            <local:SearchParameter Value="Amount" Content="{StaticResource TextBoxValue}"/>
            <local:SearchParameter Value="Date" Content="{StaticResource DatePickerValue}"/>
        </x:Array>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <TextBlock Text="Search By"/>
    <ComboBox Name="TrSearchBy" SelectedIndex="0"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedParameter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
              ItemsSource="{DynamicResource SearchParameters}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ValuePresenter}"/>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Value, ElementName=TrSearchBy}" />
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedItem.Content, ElementName=TrSearchBy}" />
    <Button Content="Search" Click="DoSearch" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I still believe, he should get familiar first with the concepts I mentioned above (your solution uses them too except the ViewModel, which is crucial for longterm WPF-Programming IMHO)... I'd never use a Control as it's own Datacontext, Even DP's should be used in UserControls only... My opinion however :)

Comment: @dba I agree with you.